# How can I get the current contents of an element in webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I must be thinking about this wrong.

I want to get the contents of an element, in this case a formfield, on a page that I am accessing with Webdriver/Selenium 2

Here is my broken code:

```
 Element=driver.find_element_by_id(ElementID)
 print Element
 print Element.text
```

here is the result:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement object at 0x9c2392c>
```

(Notice the blank line)
I know that element has contents since I just stuffed them in there with the previous command using .sendkeys  and I can see them on the actual web page while the script runs.

but I need to get the contents back into data.

What can I do to read this?  Preferably in a generic fashion so that I can pull contents from varied types of elements.

Comment: what kind of element is it? If it's an input element you need the attribute "value" instead of text

Comment: Ah,  Value could be the solution.  Will be trying.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

I believe prestomanifesto was on the right track.  It depends on what kind of element it is.  You would need to use `element.get_attribute('value')` for input elements and `element.text` to return the text node of an element.

You could check the WebElement object with `element.tag_name` to find out what kind of element it is and return the appropriate value.

This should help you figure out:

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.w3c.org')
element = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
element.send_keys('hi mom')

element_text = element.text
element_attribute_value = element.get_attribute('value')

print element
print 'element.text: {0}'.format(element_text)
print 'element.get_attribute(\'value\'): {0}'.format(element_attribute_value)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does this same method works if there are multiple classes in a row, and you want to get the text of each class in that row?

Answer (score 70):

```
element.get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

Comment: really useful command to get the attributes that do not actually appear on the page such as hrefs etc. plus 1

Comment: to get the element as well: `element.get_attribute('outerHTML')`

Comment: Found a Winner!

Answer (score 4):

I know when you said "contents" you didn't mean this, but if you want to find all the values of all the attributes of a webelement this is a pretty nifty way to do that with javascript in python:

```
everything = b.execute_script(
    'var element = arguments[0];'
    'var attributes = {};'
    'for (index = 0; index < element.attributes.length; ++index) {'
    '    attributes[element.attributes[index].name] = element.attributes[index].value };'
    'var properties = [];'
    'properties[0] = attributes;'
    'var element_text = element.textContent;'
    'properties[1] = element_text;'
    'var styles = getComputedStyle(element);'
    'var computed_styles = {};'
    'for (index = 0; index < styles.length; ++index) {'
    '    var value_ = styles.getPropertyValue(styles[index]);'
    '    computed_styles[styles[index]] = value_ };'
    'properties[2] = computed_styles;'
    'return properties;', element)
```

you can also get some extra data with `element.__dict__`.

I think this is about all the data you'd ever want to get from a webelement.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on this answer: [How can I get the current contents of an element in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10259649/5847502)
just more like copy-paste.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.w3c.org')
element = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
element.send_keys('hi mom')

element_text = element.text
element_attribute_value = element.get_attribute('value')

print (element)
print ('element.text: {0}'.format(element_text))
print ('element.get_attribute(\'value\'): {0}'.format(element_attribute_value))


element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.description.expand_description > p')
element_text = element.text
element_attribute_value = element.get_attribute('value')

print (element)
print ('element.text: {0}'.format(element_text))
print ('element.get_attribute(\'value\'): {0}'.format(element_attribute_value))
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -12):

In Java its *Webelement.getText()* . Not sure about python.

Comment: The question tag implies that it is about `python`