# How can I get the inner text of an element in Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with a [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) node:

```html
<input
    type="form-control"
    type="text"
    data-bind="textInput: EnterpriseId"
    disabled 
    autocomplete="off">
```

How can I get its value? I'm struggling since `element.getText()` does not work and returns a blank.

Comment: Can you show us some of your research please?

Comment: have you tried `element.getAttribute("value") `

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[How to gettext() of an element in Selenium Webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22087952/how-to-gettext-of-an-element-in-selenium-webdriver)*

Comment: [Reference for the `disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autocomplete). But what is `data-bind`? What is the consequence for the doubled `type` attribute?

Comment: Perhaps the title should be more specific?

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```java
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("id value"));  
String val = element.getAttribute("innerText")
```

Comment: can you share your By locator ? and code that you tried

Comment: dude, u r deviating from the topic, why do u need the By locator here. I am just asking how to get an input type="text" value when the value attribute is not present for this element in the DOM

Comment: might be your locator and the way u wrote ur code snippet have some error.

Comment: I'm getting: `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'getAttribute'` but this is in python

Comment: that's because you're using webdriver's java API instead of python's API

Answer (score 2):

I presume the element in question is an [<input>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) element, so you may be able to use the `element.getAttribute(String attribute)` method like so:

```java
String value = element.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: there is no value attribute as I can see in this element tag

Comment: Ok for the given element `<input type = "form-control" type="text" data-bind="textInput: EnterpriseId" disabled autocomplete="off">`, what exactly are you trying to get hold of?

Can you share a screenshot of the element?

Comment: i cannot get screenshots, this in an input text field which contains a value inside but the DOM does not display the value here. So i am not able to get the input field's text

Answer (score 1):

This *[input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text)* tag is disabled, hence `element.getText()` returns a blank value.

Use `element.getAttribute("textContent")` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for the placeholder of an input text, because you might try:

```
element.getAttribute("placeholder");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go to your browser → open developer tools → inspect element you want to take attribute from → click *Properties* → check if that value is in `InnerText`.

Then do as it is mentioned in previous comments:

```
element_locator.get_attribute('InnerText')
```

Comment: In Firefox (at least 106.0.2), it is "Inspector" (invoke it by menu *Tools* → *Browser Tools* → *Web Developer Tools*. Or if the *"Tools"* menu is hidden: `Alt` + `T`. Or keyboard shortcut `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` to open Web Developer Tools): 1) Click *"Pick an element from the page"* (or `Shift` + `Ctrl` + `C`). 2) Left click on an element on the page. 3) Right-click on the selected HTML line. 4) Choose *Copy* → *XPath*.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue! This post solved it for me:
*[How can I get the current contents of an element in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251525/how-can-i-get-the-current-contents-of-an-element-in-webdriver)*

I used:

```py
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//button[@class="size-grid-dropdown size-grid-button"]')
element.text
```

Comment: why are you posting a python answer to an obviously *java* question? Even if you say it's not clear at all the rest of the answers are written for java...

Answer (score 0):

It works definitely, as I've tested it several times:

```html
<input type="form-control" type="text" data-bind="textInput: EnterpriseId" disabled autocomplete="off">
```

In your example, you don’t have any `innerText`. So you can only get attributes as mentioned before with the existing attributes. In your case:
type, data-bind, EnterpriseId and autocomplete. No value will be as this attribute isn’t created.

If you want to get only existing, this should be fine:

```java
String example = driver.findElement(ByLocator(("")).getAttribute("any attribute of your input");
System.out.println(example);
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's suggested, HTML's [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/text) nodes don't have a text attribute because they can store data in multiple formats in a **value** attribute.

This can be easily seen in the [HTML `input` API specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#htmlinputelement) where this `form control` can be of type *`radio`*, *`date`*, *`file upload`* and many more.

So, in your specific case, I'd suggest you check the `webdriver`'s API for a method that's able to retrieve the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

As a bonus to evaluate innerText of an element within Selenium:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yourEl")));
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.attributeToBe(By.id("yourEl"), "innerText", yourValue));
```

Documentation: *[attributeToBe](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#attributeToBe(org.openqa.selenium.By,java.lang.String,java.lang.String))*

Answer (score 0):

Faced a similar issue, I wanted web driver to wait until a particular text appeared in 2 web elements.so did a do while until the condition passed.

```
String val = "", val1 = "";
        do {
            val = (commonMethods.getElementByXpath(chromedriver, 1000, elements.trasmitBandwidthText))
                    **.getAttribute("innerText");**

            val1 = (commonMethods.getElementByXpath(chromedriver, 1000, elements.receiveBandwidthText))
                    **.getAttribute("innerText");**

            System.out.println(pod + "--- " + val + " value !!!!!!" + val1);
        } while (!(val.contains(pod) && val1.contains(pod)));
```

.getAttribute("innerText") helps get text inside an element.