# how to click on a webpage all buttons with specific text, one by one

Tags: python, api, selenium, web-scraping, quora

I have [this](https://www.quora.com/Have-you-ever-countined-to-pursue-someone-who-wasnt-interested-in-you) quora webpage as a sample

It does contain 4 "View Upvoters" buttons
Using this code, I want to get all 4 button in order to click them one by one later.

```
upvoter_list = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'AnswerVoterListModalLink')))
```

`print(len(upvoter_list))` gives me 4, which is correct
when I print the text of the first element of `upvoter_list`

```
print(upvoter_list[0].text)
```

I get 'view upvoters' as a result
but when I print the remaining, i get the empty result,

```
print(upvoter_list[1].text)
```

what is the problem?

Comment: I see only 2 buttons and text printed for both as expected

Comment: No, there is 4 view upvotes buttons, when you print the text of the first element of upvoter_list you get 'view upvotes', but for the remaining you get empty result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this (updated)

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
obj = webdriver.Chrome('path to driver')


list_of_upvoters = []
obj.get('https://www.quora.com/Have-you-ever-countined-to-pursue-someone-who-wasnt-interested-in-you')
sleep(5)
obj.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
sleep(5)
obj.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,1);")
sleep(5)

for p in obj.find_elements_by_class_name('AnswerVoterListModalLink'):
    sleep(5)
    p.click()
    sleep(10)
    for div in obj.find_elements_by_class_name('author_info'):
        list_of_upvoters.append(div.find_element_by_class_name('user').text)
    print(list_of_upvoters)
    list_of_upvoters = []
    sleep(10)
    obj.find_element_by_class_name('modal_close').click()
    sleep(10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, what do i have to add in order to get the content generated by the click event? which is in this case  the name of the upvoters

Comment: Note that p.click () is giving me error code, element not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Try `get_attribute("textContent")` instead of `text`.

[How to get inner text of an element in Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933778/how-to-get-inner-text-of-an-element-in-selenium)