# What are some ways to access WebElement objects contents?

Tags: python

I have a WebElement object but would like to use further search functions to access smaller html elements and their various characteristics. element.text yields all the text, but I would also like to find the href values inside the object, preferably using the xpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from another question that someone answered for finding WebElements attributes: [How can I get the current contents of an element in webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251525/how-can-i-get-the-current-contents-of-an-element-in-webdriver)

I've since used element.get_attribute('innerHTML') however it only provides the raw html in string form, I'm not sure how to use more selenium search functions like xpath.