# Finding shadow DOM text with Selenium and CSS

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I am trying to locate an input text from input field that is saved in shadow DOM with:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#my_id div:nth-of-type(2)").text
```

but it does not help.
HTML part

```html
<input _ngcontent-c21="" class="clr-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="my_id" name="my_id" placeholder="My placeholder namespace" size="40" type="text">
 #shadow-root {user-agent}
  <div pseudo="-webkit-input-placeholder" id="placeholder" style="display: none !important;">My placeholder namespace</div>
  <div>Text I need to find</div>
```

Also tried this with not luck:

```
shadow_section = driver.execute_script('''return 
document.querySelector("#my_id").shadowRoot''')
            print(shadow_section.find_element_by_css_selector("div:nth-of-type(2)").text)
```

What is the best approach for finding elements in shadow DOM in this case?
In my case locator should be linked to  element.

Update: as suggested I tried:

```
  shadow_root = driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].shadowRoot', driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#my_id"))
  shadow_root_element = shadow_root(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div:nth-child(2)'))
```

But received:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

on `shadow_root_element` row.

Comment: You can not query ``user-agent`` shadowRoots. Those are Browser specific implementations. So the HTML in Safari *could* be different from the HTML in Chrome or FireFox. If try to edit it (double-click) in F12 Elements.. you can't.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood it in a hard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find a solution with Javascripts .shadowRoot option and it is a mystery for me why it does not work.
This option works just fine. It input text:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#my_id").get_attribute("value")
```

or

```
driver.find_element_by_id("my_id").get_attribute("value")
```

I am still very interested in the approach proposed by PDHide.

Comment: in the example you showed there is no attribute called value , then how will this work?

Comment: Do you have a website link?

Comment: The site closed app. I found this answer useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10251525/how-can-i-get-the-current-contents-of-an-element-in-webdriver . So, in the case of input elements we should use "element.get_attribute('value')". Also, from what I learned it matters what type of #shadow-root it is. In my case it is {user-agent}. I think in other cases javascript approach would work with no problems.

Comment: There is no value attribute in my HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
element=driver.execute_script(
    "return document.querySelector('#my_id').shadowRoot.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)')")
```

you have to use execute script to find shadow root, the element will have the item you want. You can now use element.text to  get the text

Comment: Thanks. When I execute this, I get:  selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null

Comment: I found this answer for Java, trying to use it in Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380091/how-to-interact-with-the-elements-within-shadow-root-open-while-clearing-brow

Comment: Make sure there is only one element we the id as my id

Comment: This id is unique, I checked it in Chrome devtools before. Maybe I should try a different locators for element in shadow DOM.

Comment: Find that element and then pass that to execute script and do arguments[0].shadowRoot

Comment: So you know the element root is actually being found

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question. I get this error on shadow_root_element

Comment: `driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].shadowRoot.querySelector('div:nth-child(2)')", driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#my_id"))`

Comment: Use locator like this

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is not ordinary DOM. I got "javascript error: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null" when executing the latest selector. I found a simplier option and I will post it shortly.

Comment: Posted working option. I will try options with execute_script tomorrow.