# How to get a text with selenium if the element doesn't show it?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, primefaces

I'm new using selenium. I am with some issues. I need to get the text or value of an element, but it isn't showed in HTML code.

For example, in this site (https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputText.xhtml?jfwid=ec4b4) if I type something in the first input text, the text/value isn't showed in HTML code, so I can't assert it.

[image]

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code. It worked for me.

```
    driver.get("https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputText.xhtml?jfwid=27a6e");     
    WebElement textfield = driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt302"));
    textfield.sendKeys("selenium");
    System.out.println(textfield.getAttribute("value"));
```

Comment: I've tried this a time ago, but it didn't work. I don't know why, but now it worked! Thank you guys for all the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try getting field's attribute named `value`:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(input[id=j_idt302])).getAttribute("value");
```

I had a similar question once [Finding shadow DOM text with selenium and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483982/finding-shadow-dom-text-with-selenium-and-css)

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//input[@id='username2']")).getAttribute("value")