# Need help to click on the element under the shadow Root (user-agent) type

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver, testng

As I don't have experience in handling shadow-root element, I am unable to click on this button called "Choose File"

I'm trying to click on "Choose File" button under shadow-root (user-agent) element, can I get help with the code.

Html Code below::

```html
<input class="webbrowse" id="web263">
  #shadow-root (user-agent)
    <input type="button" value="Choose File">
      #shadow-root (user-agent)
        "Choose File"
      </input>
      <span aria-hidden="true">No file chosen</span>
</input>
```

Thank you all i really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you tried any code? Are you getting any error?

Comment: I tried, not working, Not Clicking on the button

Comment: https://cutt.ly/Qn3RjW3 check this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a very similar problem and could not find a solution with `JavascriptExecutor`

I tried this method and it never worked. Locator is not a problem.

```
elem = driver.execute_script('return document.querySelector(".clr-form-control .clr-input").shadowRoot.querySelector("#picker")')
elem.click()
```

**Solution**

I'm using Python, but the idea is the same. The solution is based on my case.

What I see in Chrome:

[image]

What Selenium Chromium-browser sees:

[image]

As you can see that Selenium is not capable to define and consequently click an element in `#shadow-root (user-agent)`
It can only get a text from there. Check this answer to see how [Finding shadow DOM text with Selenium and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66483982/finding-shadow-dom-text-with-selenium-and-css)

However, you can click your element, that's located in `#shadow-root (user-agent)` with `ActionChains`

This is the example of my code:

```
expire_field = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".clr-form-control .clr-input")
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(expire_field)
time.sleep(1)
actions.move_by_offset(73, 0)
time.sleep(1)
actions.click().perform()
```

A few things to note from it:

- The field size with icon I want to click is 180*24 px. Icon size is 17*17 px. Thus to calculate x offset I used:
- 180/2 = 90 (the center of the whole input)
- 90-17 = 73 to calculate the x location of the calendar icon. (note that this amount can be a little different depending on a case)
- It's almost not possible to avoid a small `time.sleep` (at least for this case). Otherwise, there won't be enough time to move mouse cursor. Sleep can be less than 1 second. This is just for example.

This approach always works for me, but I agree, that it's not as stable as using traditional approaches.
Read about `move_by_offset` in detail [here](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver/selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.html#selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains.ActionChains.move_by_offset).

Answer (score 0):

make use of `JavascriptExecutor`

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].shadowRoot", driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[value = 'Choose File']")));
element.sendKeys("some keys");
```

Comment: This code is not working. Exception : No Such Element xpath selector: //input[value='Choose File']

Comment: It won't work for user-agent, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you have to access the parent node (`<input class="webbrowse" id="web263">`) and then you can locate your input:

```
WebElement element = (WebElement) ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.querySelector('.webbrowse').shadowRoot.querySelector('input[value=\"Choose File\"]');");

element.click();
```